# How to Rerun failed cmds in a build defintion

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tfs-2015, build-definition

I have a build definition,which contains a couple of cmds that run the same exe(through the commandline task) but with different params. At the end of the run of the build definition I want to rerun the failed cmds. I can write a batch file where I can check the status with %ERRORLEVEL% after each cmd run, but how do I rerun them?

Comment: Steps in your build shouldn't be occasionally failing. Address the root cause, which is the intermittent failure.

Comment: Yes I understand, I am also logging the cause of the failures every time. But since this is spread over a very broad spectrum it is possible that something might fail, but then again passes on  the 2nd run. The build def mentioned here are test scenarios, hence all the failure logs are taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above scenario I tweaked my code a bit. I isolated the main() method completely and put it inside a simple try catch block and an iterator that takes its value from a config file. It will catch as long as the iterator allows and then it will throw the exception. For now this is working for me. Lets hope MS visual studio team gives some thought about the request raised!! Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not able to rerun a failed build task in TFS vNext build for now.

I have add a uservoice for you. You could vote up and monitor it. TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

> **Rerun failed build task/step**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20067814-rerun-failed-build-task-step

For now you could only rerun the whole build definition. Another workaround is using [Conditional build tasks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2017#conditional-build-tasks) add the same task twice, which may do the trick. However this is not available for tfs2015, this feature is only available in TFS 2017 Update 2 and above.

Comment: What you said is absolutely correct, cant rerun any particular step in build definition as of now. For the above scenario I tweaked my code a bit. I isolated the main() method completely and put it inside a simple try catch block and an iterator that takes its value from a config file. It will catch as long as the iterator allows and then it will throw the exception. For now this is working for me. Lets hope MS visual studio team gives some thought about the request raised!!
Thanks anyways!!

Comment: @Reema Glad to here your issue fixed. And thanks for the sharing, you could move your solution from the comment to an answer and mark it, which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```
@echo off
cls
:a
echo Hello World! > C:\Windows\System32\file.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto b
echo Ran successfully!
pause

:b
cls
echo There was an error
pause
goto a
```